# Python : Convert from C-Char to Int

Tags: python

I have a string read in from a binary file that is unpacked using `struct.unpack` as a string of length n.

Each byte in the string is a single integer (1-byte) representing 0-255.  So for each character in the string I want to convert it to an integer.

I can't figure out how to do this.  Using ord doesn't seem to be on the right track...

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import struct
>>> a = struct.pack("ccc", "a", "b", "c")
>>> a
b'abc'
>>> b = struct.unpack("ccc", a)
>>> b
(b'a', b'b', b'c')
>>> ord(b[0])
97
>>> c = struct.pack("BBB", 1, 2, 3)
>>> c
b'\x01\x02\x03'
>>> d = struct.unpack("BBB", c)
>>> d
(1, 2, 3)
```

Works for me.

Comment: You answered my question perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: Great! Welcome to StackOverflow! Did you know that you can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark on the left?